# How to make the package run automatically on startup after installation via Advanced Installer?

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer

I have a PowerShell script which creates the MSI installer for a Python package when it is run. The MSI installer creation is working as expected and the package is correctly installed on running the installer. But I want to add the package to Windows Startup Programs so that the package starts running on system startup. Is there a way to achieve this via PowerShell Script?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to simply create within your PowerShell script a Run or RunOnce registry for your package/application. Check Microsoft docs for [Run and RunOnce Registry Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think you mean that I should set the application to run on startup directly? Actually, I want the application which will be installed using the MSI installer to run automatically on startup, which will not be available when the PowerShell script is run. I think the "add to startup" logic has to be added to the advanced installer configuration so that the application installed using that config runs on startup.

Comment: This should be possible too, in Advanced Installer when you open your setup project in Custom Actions view there is a dedicated Run inline PowerShell script action that you can use to run your PowerShell code. Just check their docs about [PowerShell custom actions](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/powershell-custom-actions.html).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to add a command for adding a shortcut to the startup folder by changing the shortcut folder location via the ApplicationShortcutFolder install parameter. I set the value of this folder to the AllUsers startup folder in Programs folder which makes the installer create a shortcut to the package on installation in the startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the installer create a shortcut to the package in the AllUsers startup folder using the following commands:

```
$startupDir = [io.path]::GetFullPath($env:AllUsersProfile)
$fullstartpath = $startupDir + "\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"                                 
$project.InstallParameters.ApplicationShortcutFolder = $fullstartpath
```